# makefile is skipping target

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following makefile for a project:

```
VIEW := View
CONTROLLER := Controller
MODEL := Model

all: compilar
compilar: criterio acta persona director jurado asistente universidad view main
    g++ -o Salida Criterio.o Acta.o Persona.o Director.o Jurado.o Asistente.o Universidad.o View.o main.o
criterio: ${MODEL}/Criterio.cpp ${MODEL}/Criterio.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Criterio.cpp
acta: ${MODEL}/Acta.cpp ${MODEL}/Acta.h ${MODEL}/Criterio.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Acta.cpp
persona: ${MODEL}/Persona.cpp ${MODEL}/Persona.h ${MODEL}/Acta.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Persona.cpp
director: ${MODEL}/Director.cpp ${MODEL}/Director.h ${MODEL}/Persona.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Director.cpp
jurado: ${MODEL}/Jurado.cpp ${MODEL}/Jurado.h ${MODEL}/Persona.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Jurado.cpp
asistente: ${MODEL}/Asistente.cpp ${MODEL}/Asistente.h ${MODEL}/Persona.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Asistente.cpp
universidad: ${MODEL}/Universidad.cpp ${MODEL}/Universidad.h ${MODEL}/Asistente.h ${MODEL}/Jurado.h ${MODEL}/Director.h ${MODEL}/Acta.h
    g++ -c ${MODEL}/Universidad.cpp
view: ${VIEW}/View.cpp ${VIEW}/View.h ${MODEL}/Universidad.h
    g++ -c ${VIEW}/View.cpp
main: main.cpp ${VIEW}/View.h 
    g++ -c main.cpp
clean: #comando para borrar los .o y el .exe
    @echo "Cleaning compilation..."
    del *.o, del *.exe
```

But when I execute make on the console it skips the target view

```
g++ -c Model/Criterio.cpp
g++ -c Model/Acta.cpp
g++ -c Model/Persona.cpp
g++ -c Model/Director.cpp
g++ -c Model/Jurado.cpp
g++ -c Model/Asistente.cpp
g++ -c Model/Universidad.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o Salida Criterio.o Acta.o Persona.o Director.o Jurado.o Asistente.o Universidad.o View.o main.o
g++: error: View.o: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, it skips the target "view" so it does not generate View.o

However if I change the name of the target "view" to something like "doview" it works perfectly. I tried looking up for reserved words on makefiles but I could not find anything related to this. Why does this happen? I'm new to makefiles.

Comment: Can you show some proof that there is no file called `view`, in the current directory, that has the appropriate timestamp?

Comment: You haven't made a target for `View.o`? You only have `view`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There is no file called view, I made a mistake naming the targets as Alan Birtles pointed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
view: ${VIEW}/View.cpp ${VIEW}/View.h ${MODEL}/Universidad.h
    g++ -c ${VIEW}/View.cpp
```

declares that you are going to create a file called `view` and that the inputs are `${VIEW}/View.cpp ${VIEW}/View.h ${MODEL}/Universidad.h`. As your command actually produces a file called `View.o` your makefile won't work. You need:

```
View.o: ${VIEW}/View.cpp ${VIEW}/View.h ${MODEL}/Universidad.h
    g++ -c ${VIEW}/View.cpp
```

(your other targets have the same issue).

You also need to mark all your targets that don't produce a file as phony:

```
.PHONY: clean all
```

As `compilar` isn't a phony target and produces a single file it should be renamed to `Salida`

Comment: I have been doing this wrong for a long time then. Thanks.

Comment: @Fawaris Make files are an arcane art, I'd recommend using something like cmake to generate them for you, that'll even generate the header file dependencies automatically from the compiler generated dependency files so you don't have to specify them manually like you are now

Comment: That sounds very useful. I will look it up, thanks a lot!